# ¿Cómo filtrar o limpiar la imagen de una huella digital con python?

Tags: python, imagen, opencv

Cómo podría obtener una huella digital en formato bmp para llegar a la segunda foto, sin ruido ni manchas con python o cualquier otro lenguaje de programación.

[image: HUELLA DIGITAL PURA]

RESULTADO ESPERADO:

[image: RESULTADO ESPERADO]

Comment: ¿Que es lo que llevas hecho hasta ahora?

Comment: intente muchos filtros con opencv y operaciones morfologicas pero no encuentro el resultado esperado.